# Webserver cannot write to directory when installing CMS

Tags: php, apache, permissions, content-management-system, selinux

I have a local stand-alone LAMP stack that I'm using for local web development.
I've tried to install multiple CMS's that all use PHP to write data to a MySQL database and files on the webserver (Concrete5, Symphony, GetSimple CMS).

However when I try to install any of these I get error messages that each state something along the lines of "the files I need to change are not writeable by the webserver."

Concrete5 error message:

> error: Web Server Access to Files and Configuration Directories
> The /config /packages and /files directories must be writable by your webserver

Symphony error message:

> Missing log file
>
> Symphony tried to create a log file and failed. Make sure the install folder is writable.

Obviously this is a permissions issue, however I've tried changing the owner & group (recursively of course) of apache's www directory to many different combinations of root, the apache user & group and my own user & group as well as set the permissions all the way to 777 using chmod, and still I get the same error from all systems.

I can drop a regular static file (like phpinfo) into the www directory and apache serves it up just fine, but no matter what I change the permissions to the CMS's cannot write to the server. What is going on?

Comment: You need to provide exact error message to get a detailed answer.

Comment: @pyrate added error messages to question

Comment: And you still getting this message when setting owner to apache user and chmod 777 for this directories?

Comment: Is it actually trying to write to `/config`??

Comment: @Jack the /config it is trying to write to is actually within the concrete5 files (/var/www/concrete5/config) not the file system level /config

Comment: @pyrate yes, even with apache owning the files and permissions at 777 this error still occurs.

Comment: Silly question, are you using seLinux?

Comment: Yes I am using SeLinux. It just comes with Fedora 16... would it cause these problems?

Comment: @jlego yeah, you'd have to explicitly grant apache permission to write into those directories ... you'd have to search online how to do that though ;-)

Comment: @Jack I will search and try to fix. Thanks

Comment: @Jack would it just be easier to turn SeLinux off? Or would that cause security issues?

Comment: @Jack I've used the SeLinux GUI tool to set booleans for allowing apache to write (as well as some for samba) and it worked. Please post the answer so I can mark it the answer.

Comment: @jlego that's great! i've added my answer.

Comment: Would you mind editing Jack's answer with the specific commands that you used so that future visitors can benefit from this question?

Comment: I used the SELinux GUI Management tool to check the required booleans. Not sure what the commands would be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use seLinux, it's not enough to give permissions using `chmod`. You have to grant apache permission to write into those folders as well.

More information can be found here: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache